# Symfony2 doctrine mysql IN query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have array of products IDs. I have to make query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid IN (1, 2, 8, 4, ...) // etc
```

I have my ids in variable $pids.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('p.pid')
            ->from('SRC\MainBundle\Entity\Product', 'p')
            ->where('p.name IN :pids') // error is HERE
            ->setParameter('pids', $pids)
            ->getQuery();
```

Doesn't work. I get an error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 66: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got ':pids'
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" actually mean? What's your issue?

Comment: i gen an error: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 66: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got ':pids'"

Comment: What happens if you wrap :pids in parenthesis like the error says?

Comment: Nope, parameterized solution is better

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What if you try

```
->where('p.name IN (:pids)') // error is HERE
```

It explicitly says to you that it expects `parentheses` but gets `placeholder`

Comment: doesn't work. [Semantical Error] line 0, col 58 near 'name IN (:pi': Error: Class SRC\MainBundle\Entity\Product has no field or association named name

Comment: @twoface88 Does that error sound right? Does your Product class have no name?

Comment: @twoface88: Doctrine doesn't think so

Comment: @twoface88 In one instance you say where **p.name** IN (...) and in another  you say **p.id** IN (...) and another you use **p.pid** IN (...) which is it?

Comment: sorry, you are RIGHT! i didn't have p.name!